# Building boost 1.63.0 with MinGW 6.3.0 on win7

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, windows-7-x64

I am learning C and C++ now and am trying to use the test Suite of Boost for TDD with Codeblocks.

After l a lot of Documentation reading, that didn´t help much, I found this:

[Building boost 1.61.0 with MinGW 5.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103244/building-boost-1-61-0-with-mingw-5-3-0)

I did it almost the same way on my System (but I had to run it as admin, what irritated me a bit, otherwise I got an Access Denied message):

So blabla add a few environmetal variables...
Then in the prompt, i did:

.\bootstrap.bat gcc
.\install toolset=gcc --prefix=C:...\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\
(without the toolset set again I got the Warning:"No Toolsets are configured" and a bunch more)

Now I get:

notice: could not find main target files
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
notice: could not find main target (x86)\boost_1_63_0\
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
don´t know how to make files
don´t know how to make (x86)\boost_1_63_0\
...found 2 targets...
...can't find 2 targets...

and the binary doesn't get built.

This is the end of the my knowledge...
Anything important I missed?

Comment: To learn C++ on Windows it is *way* easier to start with Visual Studio 2015, it's free.

Comment: Not only that, the Boost binaries for Visual C++ have already been built and available on SourceForge.

Comment: ***Anything important I missed?*** My guess from your partial path is you tried to have it install the binaries in c:\Program Files(x86) that is your problem. UAC will prevent this. Unless you are running from an elevated command prompt. A second problem is a path with spaces in it needs to be quoted.

Comment: @RustyX: Yes I know that it works with VS2015...but I don't like the IDE.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know there are the boost.built Binaries. Also not the question, but thanks for the tips.

Comment: @drescherjm yes I built it in C:\Program Files (x86)\boost_1_63_0\boost\tools\build\    So I need to put the whole Path in ""? Elevated as in Admin? And UAC?

Comment: I would just get it out of program files.

Comment: Admin is not even enough. http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/elevated.htm

Comment: @drescherjm It works now, You are officially my Hero of the last 3 Days!!! THX A LOT

Comment: @drescherjm even works without elevation

Comment: I assume you selected a folder that was not Program Files.

Comment: Yeah, I just put it in C:\boost....and changed the EVs accordingly

Comment: how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: maybe if @drescherjm summarizes his comments in an answer... ^^

Answer (score 0):

From the comments. Your main problem seems to have been you were trying to build and install boost into `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost_1_63_0`. Remember that Program Files is a UAC protected folder. It will require UAC elevation to write files to this location. See here for more info on UAC folder protection: [What makes c:\Program Files UAC-protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617004/what-makes-c-program-files-uac-protected)

A second problem is since your target path had a space in it you would have to quote the space when passing the command line parameters to build boost.

For both problems I recommend that instead of installing and building from C:\Program Files build from a different folder on your drive preferably one without spaces in the folder name.