# C++ | How can i delete files in a folder located in (C:\Program Files (x86))

Tags: c++, delete-file

So here is my issue, i would like to delete folders that are located in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata'

so to be clear in userdata there is multiple folder, and i want to clear userdata(remove everything in userdata) but i dont want to delete userdata itself.

i tried multiple things but so far none worked, i was only able to delete .txt like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


int main() {


   remove("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\userdata\\test.txt");
    

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Spawning a shell to call remove is a terrible way to do it. Since you're on Windows you can use the [DeleteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) function

Comment: Also make sure you have privilege to delete that file.

Comment: Use [`std::filesystem::remove_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) instead and invoke program with administrator rights.

Comment: @brc-dd `remove_all` also removes the directory. OP wants it to not be deleted.

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)"  is protected by UAC. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617004)

Comment: @Casey then maybe create it again after deleting? [std::filesystem::create_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory). Moreover I also suspect that steam will create it again if it didn't find it. Also one possible cause that the OP is unable to delete the directory is that the files are being used by steam or its service.

Comment: And why are you putting user files there? They should be in $HOME/AppData/...

Comment: @user207421 There is nothing like `$HOME` in Windows (unless you manually create suitable environment variable). Although there is `%appdata%`. Moreover it is the choice of Steam developers not the OP.

Comment: I believe there is a %USERPROFILE% environment variable but I do agree that the location of the files is a Steam choice.

Comment: You're using `system` anyway. Why don't you just to `CD <complete name here>` then `DEL *`?

Answer (score 1):

I thinks, You need Permission for doing file operations in C Drive, Just run your program with adminstrator rights!

Comment: Well i tried and it did not work either, the thing is i would like to remove all the file in "userdata". and doing :  remove("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\userdata"); will remove the folder userdata wich i dont want :/

Comment: Go to folder userdata and remove each file via loop

Answer (score 0):

You could call `std::filesystem::remove_all`, but this also removes the supplied directory. Because of the requirement that the parent directory remain, you'll have to use a loop:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    for(std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter{std::filesystem::path{"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/"}};
        std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator{};
        ++iter)
    {
        std::filesystem::remove(*iter);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, take a look at this answer. This is the only platform independent solution. System calls are really not a good idea!

Comment: Nice call but even when i include <filesystem> it doesnt recognize 'std::filesystem' and 'iter'. Any idea ?

Comment: @LazyToxic You make no mention of what compiler, version, and language setting you are using. If C++17 mode (or higher) is not turned on nor supported, it won't work.